# 10.15.0 - [FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM018000] Could not find current app version

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I'm building a flutter app for iOS but when I try to build it this is the error I encounter.

I set the version in the pubspec.yaml file

```yaml
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.0"
```

and also in Xcode (in runner - general) I set version = 1.0.0, build=1

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the cocoapods for Firebase Messaging but didn't help.